# How can I remove rust from a washing machine cabinet and protect against future corrosion?

Tags: rust-removal, rust-proofing, rust

The edges of body of the washing machine near the detergent dispenser & just above the front door is getting rusted.

I have tried cleaning it with rough & smooth emery paper. Also applied potato covered with salt. Then painted the affected area.

The problem still persists. Please help

Comment: why are you rubbing salt on it?. Salt causes rust. I would clean the area (emery is ok, no salt) and apply some appliance epoxy paint.

Comment: Is "Potato + salt in washing machine on hot cycle" like wrapping a chicken in foil and sticking it on your engine for 100 miles to cook it?

Comment: Salt is commonly used to remove rust. Just the other day I used aluminum foil and salt water to clean up chrome on an old motorcycle. Worked very well.

Comment: In what way does the problem persist? Is it rusting through the new paint? Is the enamel/ceramic worn away where it's rusting? A clear photo might be helpful.

Comment: @isherwood, the aluminum foil and salt water may have some electrolytic properties that remove rust ... it is probably not the salt that does the cleaning .... not sure if potato and salt have the same effect

Comment: @isherwood- Yup. It is rusting through the new paint. Will share a picture soon.

Comment: I am not able to add image using Ctrl+G. Someone pls help, how to add image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since no one has addressed the real problem here, recurring rust, I will. Your rust keeps coming back because it is rusting from the inside out, plain and simple. It may not seem like it at first, but from my experience, if and when you clean rust and seal the surface, but the rust keeps coming back, that's because it's rusting from the inside out. You need to inspect the inside of your machine and its internal structure and look for any internal leaks. Once you identify the internal problem and resolve it, then you can again clean the rust and seal the surface because there is no internal rust that will come through again.
I hope this helps.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Thanks for the answer; keep 'em coming. And, you should [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how better to contribute here.